# Apollo GraphQL Server Increase Keep-Alive Timeout

Tags: node.js, express, apollo, apollo-server, nodejs-server

I'm developing an app with an Apollo-Server backend (using express). Initial queries take about 2 seconds to get responses, but then subsequent (within around 5 seconds) are much quicker. Then after around 5 seconds the first query will once again take longer.

[Example of duration of requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiMnj.png)

[Response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLOIt.png)

I assume this is due to the `Keep-Alive timeout=5` header that is sent in responses. If this is the issue, how would I go about increasing this on my server?